Targeted in .dropDestination doesn't get set to false
I have a circle as a drop target. When the user drags something over, the circle should grow in size, but stay at the same position.
This is what I have:
struct TestView: View {
    @State var isDragOver = false

    var body: some View {
        let size = 20.0
        let backgroundSize = isDragOver ? 6 * size : 2 * size

        Circle()
            .fill(.black)
            .frame(width: backgroundSize, height: backgroundSize)
            .dropDestination(for: URL.self) { _, _ in
                // do something
                return true
            } isTargeted: { targeted in
                withAnimation {
                    isDragOver = targeted
                }
            }
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
    }
}

This generally does what I want, but it stops working when I add a WebView in the background:
#Preview {
    ZStack {
        WebView()
        TestView()
            .padding(40)
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                   maxHeight: .infinity,
                   alignment: .bottomTrailing)
    }
}

When I drag something over and quickly move it away again, the isDragOver is not set to false.
It also works, if I:

Replace the WebView with e.g. this:

Text("hello")
    .draggable(URL(string: "google.com")!) {
        Text(verbatim: "string")
    }


remove the withAnimation
remove the .frame(width: size, height: size)

What can I try to fix or work around this? Thanks!

WebView
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        if let requestUrl = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
            webView.load(request)
        }
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        //
    }
}


does this issue happens in Preview or on real devices.

It happens in the Preview, Simulator and on a real device. The dragging inside the Preview seems to cancel automatically after a short time though.

No idea where that issue is coming from, but my workaround is to not animate the actual circle (and make it basically invisible) and instead animate one in the background:
Circle()
    .fill(.black.opacity(0.001)) // <-- make this invisible
    .frame(width: backgroundSize, height: backgroundSize)
    .dropDestination(for: URL.self) { _, _ in
        // do something
        return true
    } isTargeted: { targeted in
        isDragOver = targeted
    }
    .background {
        Circle() // <-- animate this background circle
            .fill(.black)
            .frame(width: backgroundSize, height: backgroundSize)
            .animation(.default, value: isDragOver)
    }
    .frame(width: size, height: size)

